# init method not working Ext.app.Application in ExtJS 4.1.0

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs4, extjs4.1

init method not working in Ext.app.Application in Ext JS 4.1.0

http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/api/Ext.app.Application

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Issue is fixed in Ext JS 4.1.1 version.

init method now gets called before launch function of Ext.app.Application in Ext JS 4.1.1